# Precision in Game Engine Physics (eg TrackMania "Press Forward Maps")

Tags: game-engine, game-physics, game-development

For some time now, I've been thinking about how games calculate physics. Take as an example the game TrackMania. There are special routes where you only have to accelerate from the beginning to get to the finish. As an example, I take the following YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uK7Y7zyP_SY). Unfortunately, I'm not a specialist in game development, but I know roughly how an engine works.
Most engines use a game loop, which means they use the delta value between the last call and the current call. This delta value is used to move objects, detect collisions and so on. The higher the delta value, the farther the object must have moved. The principle works fine with many games, but not with TrackMania.
A PC that can only display 25 FPS would calculate the physics differently than a PC with 120 FPS, because the collision detection is more accurate (impact is detected earlier, speed adjusted accordingly, ...). Now you can assume that the delta value is always the same (as with Super Mario Maker, at least that's my assumption), then this would work. But that would cause problems similar to old games (https://superuser.com/questions/630769/why-do-some-old-games-run-much-to-quickly-on-modern-hardware/).

Now my question, why do such maps work on every PC and why is the physics always exactly the same? Did I miss any aspect of game development / engine development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple, first the physic of the game is predictable, based on the input the result will always be the same.

Then the physic loop is not the same as the render, the game ensure the physic loop will be call with exactly the same period every time during the whole execution. So, yes a delta is needed for the render part, but the physic as a constant time in ms between each iteration.

One last think : you wont find "Press Forward" maps on the multiplayer, these kind of maps will not work correctly, this is directly linked to specificities in the physic to avoid TAS (Tool Assisted Speedrun).

Comment: Oh okay. That makes more sense. Thanks :)

Comment: Some more questions:
1: So the render loop just tries to simulate a "small" version of the physic engine to simulate a smooth movement (interpolate)?
2: Is the render loop in a different thread than the physic loop (to avoid blocking the physic engine)? 
3: Would the car in TrackMania move slower, when the execution time of the physic loop would be higher than the const time interval?
4: The timer which calls the physic engine will not be perfect, so the const time intervall will be a little bit different. Can this be ignored because the difference is too low?

Comment: 1. Yes, the render loop draw frame that is the graphical representation of the physic at a specific time.
Another very important thing : to be able to do an interpolation we need two physic steps so the frames you see every second is an interpolation between these physic steps, so you always see we a very little lag, this lag is the minimal since the interval between two physic steps is small.

Comment: 2. In lots of games this is the case but in trackmania since you store player inputs and the physic is predictable you can still compute accurately the current step and a previous step to do an interpolation. In conclusion you game can lag but the position of your car will always be exact in every rendered frame.
3. If you call the physic loop more often than the value defined has the interval the answer is yes. But if you simply reduce the const interval value you will only have a better interpolation in render.

Comment: 4. True the time isn’t perfect but this is like precision issue with float/double value, you can do lots of algorithmic tricks to compensate but in the end this isn't significant.

Comment: Do you have any more info about the avoidance of TAS?